# Get current Work item data in VSTS Extension

Tags: azure-devops, vssdk

I am want to create a VSTS Extension for TFS 2015 Update 3 and I want to start slow. I want to create a custom action that shows the Id and the Title of the current Work Item in one pop up window.

I have been reading the tutorials but I still don't get it.

I used this example from GitHub:

```
var showPropertiesMenuProvider = (function () {
"use strict";
return {
    showPropertiesInDialog: function(properties, title) {

        VSS.getService("ms.vss-web.dialog-service").then(function (dialogSvc) {

            var extInfo = VSS.getExtensionContext();

            var contibution = VSS.getContribution();

            var dialogOptions = {
                title: title || "Properties",
                width: 800,
                height: 600,
                buttons: null
            };

            var contributionConfig = { 
                properties: properties
            };

            dialogSvc.openDialog(extInfo.publisherId + "." + extInfo.extensionId + "." + "contextForm", dialogOptions, contributionConfig);
        });
    },
    execute: function(actionContext) {
        this.showPropertiesInDialog(actionContext);
    }
};
}());

VSS.register("showProperties", function (context) {
    return showPropertiesMenuProvider;
});
```

which gives me a lot of information but I still can't extract the data I need.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the target of the action? ms.vss-work-web.backlog-item-menu?

Comment: No, it is the ms.vss-work-web.work-item-context-menu.

Comment: @spirosvp Do you use Contributions Guide extension directly (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide) or build it by yourself according the source code (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/contributions-guide)? Are there any error in developer tool (F12 for IE, Console tab)

Comment: @starain Yes you are correct this is a part from the Contributions Guide extension and no there are no errors in the developer Tool.

Comment: @spirosvp How do you install that extension? Did you download the extension (vsix file), then uploaded and installed in your TFS?

Comment: There isn't any issue with your code to show the dialog. Can you share the code how you get the workitem information in "contextForm" contribution?